# Reactjs : craco + antd => rule priority rule mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, antd, craco

I'm migrating from pure Webpack to CRA template and I'm using antd, so I'm trying to implement  [craco-antd](https://github.com/DocSpring/craco-antd) package, but I'm facing an issue :
the antd rule are more prioritized than mine in the generated inline css :

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.less';
import './theme.less';
```

### craco.config.js

```
const CracoAntDesignPlugin = require("craco-antd");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoAntDesignPlugin
        }
    ]
};
```

### Result :

[image: The antd rules are above mine]

edit : I don't have the same behavior on prod and debug build =>
prod OK
debug KO

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this? I wonder why this isn't a problem for most people.

Comment: I don't reproduce the issue anymore, I think it was an issue on the React debug mode from what I saw...